# Move /var and /usr to another lvm - Centos 7

Tags: centos, lvm

I need to migrate /var and /usr to another lv to remove the physical disks used by it today , any one have an idea on how can I do it?

```
  LV      VG     Attr       LSize    
  lvroot  rootvg -wi-ao----   10,00g
  lvusr   rootvg -wi-ao---- <110,00g
  lvvar   rootvg -wi-ao---- <123,90g
```

I was thinking to move lvusr and lvvar to lvroot (I can expand that disk if needed), but I couldn't find the steps for it.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of LVM is that LVs are like fluid that can be poured from one PV to another. It seems you could achieve your actual goal by moving the `lvusr` and `lvvar` LVs to another PV. That can be achieved on-line, without unmounting anything.

The alternative (moving the contents of those LVs to `lvroot`) would require unmounting `lvusr` and `lvvar`, which will most likely require a reboot to emergency mode to achieve, as unmounting `/usr` or `/var` is not going to succeed while the system is running normally.

If you can add new physical disks, you can add them to the `rootvg`:

```
<optionally partition the new disk>
pvcreate /dev/<disk or partition>
vgextend rootvg /dev/<disk or partition>
```

If you can expand an existing physical disks you wish to keep (e.g. disk `/dev/sdX`) and the LVM PV is located as the last partition on the disk (partition number N), you can expand the existing PV after expanding the disk:

```
growpart /dev/sdXN   # or use gparted or similar
pvresize /dev/sdXN
```

Or if the PV is on a whole-disk device (e.g. `/dev/sdX` with no partition number), you can just expand the PV after expanding the disk:

```
pvresize /dev/sdX
```

Or if the expanded disk is partitioned and the PV is not the last partition, you can create a new partition using the added space, and add it to the VG:

```
fdisk /dev/sdX   # to create a new partition, e.g. /dev/sdXNN
pvcreate /dev/sdXNN
vgextend rootvg /dev/sdXNN
```

---

After any of these 4 procedures, your `rootvg` should now have unallocated space in it, as indicated by `vgs` or `vgdisplay rootvg`. To move the LV from its current PV to the free space, use `pvmove`.

If you don't care where the data will be moved (or there is just one chunk of free space available in the VG), you can simply specify the device name of the PV you want to move data away from:

```
pvmove /dev/<old disk or partition containing a LVM PV>
vgreduce rootvg /dev/<old disk or partition containing a LVM PV>
pvremove /dev/<old disk or partition containing a LVM PV>
```

The `vgreduce` step will only proceed if all the LV data has been successfully moved away: if the move was not successful, `vgreduce` will tell you that the PV is still in use and refuse to remove the PV from the rootvg.

If you want, you can explicitly specify one or more target PVs for the pvmove:

```
pvmove /dev/<old PV> /dev/<new PV that is already part of the same VG> ...
```

The `pvmove` command will move data from the old PV to the first new PV until it's fully allocated, then move on to the other listed PVs in order as necessary. (Yes, a single LV can occupy multiple PVs without problems.)

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want is "to merge logical LVM volumes". It can't and won't work in your case because they already contain distinct data, i.e. filesystems.

What you can do is delete unneeded logical volumes, grow the remaining ones, move the data (`sudo mv source destination` under a LiveCD), delete the source logical volumes, and again grow the remaning ones.

Before you attempt to do any of that, make sure you've got everything backed up.